# foreach loop with curl multi exec

Tags: curl, foreach, curl-multi

I am Trying to find out how to send multiple curl requests with help of curl multi exec inside foreach loop. I wrote some of code, But it is not showing me fetch data, I don't understand,

Thanks For Helping out in advance

Here is my Code:

```
<?php $multiCurl = array();  

 $result = array();

 $mh = curl_multi_init();

 foreach ($members as $mem => $id) {
$c = $mem["ta"];
$urll = "https://api.abcd.com/" . urlencode($c);
$tokenq = "abcd";
$multi[$mem] = curl_init();
 $headr = array();
$headr[] = "Accept: application/json";
 $headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$tokenq;
 curl_setopt($multi[$mem], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
 curl_setopt($multi[$mem], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($multi[$mem], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($multi[$mem], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multi[$mem]);
  }
 $index=null;
  do {
 curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
 } while($index > 0);
 // get content and remove handles
 foreach($multi as $kp => $ch6) {
 $result[$kp] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch6);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch6);
  }
  // close
  curl_multi_close($mh);
```

On the other hand when I use curl_init single request it returns with data but not working with curl multi exec,it returns with this thing.

> Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => [34] => [35] => [36] => [37] => [38] => [39] => [40] => [41] => [42] => [43] => [44] => [45] => [46] => [47] => [48] => [49] => )

I hope i will get some answer!! :-)

Comment: just read your error logs, and PHP literally tells you what you're doing wrong. make sure you have `error_reporting=E_ALL` in php.ini, and execute the code, and check the error logs. hint, you're doing the same mistake over and over again, on line 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, and 19.

Comment: Thanks for Helping Out, It worked For Me Now!! :-) ;-)